# Writing text user input into excel

Tags: python, excel, input, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl. The user is asked to input many numbers and those get written to excel just fine, but I need to change the code for it to also write text input into excel. What and how do I need to change?

```
for rowNum in range(1, 5):
name = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
if name in Dictionary1:
    sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value = Dictionary1[name]
```

I suppose that the 'value' part is the problem, that needs to be changed for text?

Comment: What's the actual question? openpyxl doesn't care whether you're adding text or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want:

```
for rowNum in range(1, 5):
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=rowNum, max_row=rowNum, max_col=1):
        for cell in row:
            name = cell.value
            if name in Dictionary1:
                cell.offset(column=1).value = Dictionary1[name]
```